# Set position of text after slide-in

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have the following code to have text slide in, but after the slide is over the text moves to the left. How would I make the text stay where it is when the slide is over?

```html
<style>
  div.slide-left {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  div.slide-left p {
    animation: slide-left 5s;
    font-size: 300%;
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
  }
  @keyframes slide-left {
    from {
      margin-left: 100%;
      width: 300%;
    }
    to {
      margin-left: 50%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
</style>
<div class="slide-left">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`animation-fill-mode: forwards`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) to preserve the last animation state. Since there was no animation-fill-mode specified, it used the default properties of the class name, i.e. resets/jumps to the top value specified  after the animation is completed.

```html
<style>
  div.slide-left {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  div.slide-left p {
    animation: slide-left 5s;
    font-size: 300%;
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
  @keyframes slide-left {
    from {
      margin-left: 100%;
      width: 300%;
    }
    to {
      margin-left: 50%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
</style>
<div class="slide-left">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```